# Django Javascript Output

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to render html output that is generated by a python google maps library that involves JS code in it. I am passing the part that shows google map with the html_map variable, and as follows:

```
html = t.render(Context({'html_map':html_map}))
return HttpResponse(html)
```

However, instead of showing the map, the page shows js code(i.e., directly prints it). The image below shows this:

[image: Output]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html = t.render(Context({'html_map':html_map}))
return HttpResponse(html)
```

use in template:

```
{{ htm_map|safe }}
```

Comment: I don't even know Django, but this looks correct since the OP is  escaping HTML that doesn't need escaping